# Understanding Hershel-Maxwell derivation of the normal distribution

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, normal-distribution, functional-equations

property 1: the probability density depends only on the distance from the origin

property 2: the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are independent from each other

let:

$$f(x,y) = f(r) = f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) = f(x)f(y)$$
let $h(x)$ be a helper function such that:
$$h(x) = f(\sqrt{x}),$$
$$ h(x^2) = f(x)$$
then:
$$h(x^2+y^2) = h(x^2)h(y^2)$$
$$h(x_1+...+x_n) = h(x_1)...h(x_n)$$
$$h(n) = b^n=e^{cx}$$
then:
$$f(x) = e^{cx^2}$$
my questions are first why: $f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) = f(x)f(y)$ that propriety is true and

why the helper function also works with $n$ numbers?
$h(x_1+...+x_n) = h(x_1)...h(x_n)$  since we are dealing with the equation of a circle?

Comment: Yes, there is some abuse of notation going on. $f(x, y)$ is a function of two variables but later on it is treated as a function of one variable like in $f(r)$ and $f(x), f(y)$. Technically they should be different functions.

Comment: I meant even before the helper function; $f(x, y) = f(r)$ is already a problem since $f(x, y)$ is a function of two variables while $f(r)$ is a function of only one variable.

Comment: $$r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$   abuse of notation but still works?

Comment: That doesn't solve the notational issue because in $f(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ you are still inputting a single number $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ into $f$ but again $f(x, y)$ accepts two numbers as inputs; you should instead do something like $f(x, y) = g(r) = g(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ making clear that $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is different from $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

You got confused because there is abuse of notation going on and even the first equality has a few steps missing. Here is a more rigorous presentation:

We seek a two-variable density function $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ satisfying properties 1 and 2.

- property 1 rigorous version: "the probability density depends only on the distance from the origin" translates mathematically to: there is $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that
  $$
  f(x, y) = g(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})
  $$ This is why $f(x, y) = f(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ is abuse of notation; $f(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ doesn't make sense because $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is a two-variable function whereas $f(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ suggests it is a one-variable function.
- property 2 rigorous version: "the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are independent from each other" translates mathematically to: there are two $u : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, $v : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that
  $$
  f(x, y) = u(x) v(y)
  $$ This is why $f(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) = f(x)f(y)$ is not only abuse of notation, it has several steps missing. Firstly, it should technically be $g(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) = cg(x)g(y)$ for some constant $c$. And secondly, you don't know a priori that $u(x)v(y) = cg(x)g(y)$. That is something you have to show and that is the correct version of your first question: why is $u(x)v(y) = cg(x)g(y)$?

Collecting all of these, your first equality should look like
$$
f(x, y) = g(r) = g(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}) = u(x)v(y)
$$ and only now you can rigorously think about the problem.

Comment: It makes more sense now but why the helper function also works with n numbers? h(x1+...+xn)=h(x1)...h(xn)
 since we are dealing with the equation of a circle?

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts Do you mean $h(x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2) = h(x_1^2) \cdots h(x_n^2)$?

Comment: yes why that one holds? that doesn't look like a circle the symmetry is broken

Comment: Try it for the $n = 3$ case first: can you show $h(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = h(x^2) h(y^2) h(z^2)$?

Comment: @athalhaidis that's a sphere,I can do the computation for one value, but is there any more rigorous proof?

Comment: @SirMrpirateroberts Don't think of it geometrically. Treat it algebraically. Substitute a new variable $y^\ast$ such that $(y^\ast)^2 = y^2 + z^2$ in $h(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$ and apply the properties

Comment: $$h(x^2+(y^*)^2)$$

Comment: also why $u(x)v(y)=cg(x)g(y)
 $?